# WPF, bad texture seams on an obj model

Tags: wpf

I'm loading and texturing a model like that

```
Model3DGroup modelGroupScull = importer.Load("C:\\Users\\х\\Desktop\\a.obj");
modelScull = (GeometryModel3D)modelGroupScull.Children[0];

BitmapImage bitImageScull = new BitmapImage();
bitImageScull.BeginInit();
bitImageScull.UriSource = new Uri("C:\\Users\\х\\Desktop\\sc.jpg");
bitImageScull.EndInit();

ImageBrush imageBrushScull = new ImageBrush();
imageBrushScull.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
imageBrushScull.ImageSource = bitImageScull;

diffuseMatScull = new DiffuseMaterial();
diffuseMatScull.Brush = imageBrushScull;


modelScull.Material = diffuseMatScull;

Model3DGroup2.Children.Add(modelScull);
```

[image]

Yet the seams look strange (they looks good in 3dMax), as well as the texture inside of the object is blue. Is there a way to fix it and made the object textured inside as well?

Thanks! )

Comment: Something about texture edge mode comes up in my mind. Words like "clamp" and "wrap".

Comment: fixed the blue inside by modelScull.BackMaterial = diffuseMatScull; , but still cant' find there to change the clamp properties. )

Comment: I have this issue with the texture seams as well. I made an issue [here](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/issues/169) and I'm looking into it now. Have you found a solution to this issue?